# Match being called off because of an attempt of match-fixing in Europe's top-level football leagues

Tags: football, uefa, match-fixing

A Swedish (top-flight) league game between Gothenburg and AIK has been [postponed after an alleged match-fixing attempt](http://www.express.co.uk/sport/football/806200/Gothenburg-AIK-postponed-match-fixing-bribe-IFK-Goteborg). ([dailymail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4965654/Ex-footballer-questioned-Swedish-matcj-fixing-scandal.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Allsvenskan#Suspended_matches))

Are there any other examples of match being called off with attempt or suspicion of match-fixing in top-level leagues of UEFA associated countries?

Top-level league meaning, in case of England only Premier League but not Championship and other lower league.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Allsvenskan#Suspended_matches) on the current season of Allsvenskan ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2017_Allsvenskan&oldid=804186687#Suspended_matches)) mentions Göteborg  rather than Gothenburg.

Comment: @Martin Göteborg is the Swedish (ie. the original) name of the city and the football team

Comment: I agree with the OP about the reasons for close votes, the question is certainly not too broad, neither is it unclear..

Comment: @posef I see - I should have realized that myself. Wikipedia: [Gothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothenburg). BTW it seems that several reviewers [voted to leave open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/close/13775).